# solve the error:: revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

How to solve this error:

> revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE

This is my Java code:

```
public class DetailContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
OnClickListener {

    private TextView    phone, email;
    private int         id;
    private ImageView   call, btnEmail;
    private ContactDB   db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_contact);

        db = ContactDB.getInstance(this);

        phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_phone_number);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        call = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
        btnEmail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_email);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null)
        {
            id = b.getInt("id");
            phone.setText(b.getString("phone"));
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(b.getString("nama"));
            if (!b.getString("email").equals("null"))
            {
                email.setText(b.getString("email"));
            } else
            {
                email.setText("");
            }

        }

        call.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail_contact, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_edit:
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("id", id);
                b.putString("name", getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString());
                b.putString("email", email.getText().toString());
                b.putString("phone", phone.getText().toString());

                Intent i = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                showSettingsAlert();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == btnEmail)
        {
            if (!email.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                        Uri.fromParts("mailto", email.getText().toString(),
                                null));

                startActivity(Intent
                        .createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));

            }

        } else if (v == call)
        {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone.getText().toString()));
            startActivity(callIntent);

            //Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + phone.getText().toString());             
            //Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, call); 
            //startActivity(surf);
        }

    }

    private void showSettingsAlert()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Delete");
        alert.setMessage("Contact akan dihapus");

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                db.deleteContact(id);
                startActivity(new Intent(DetailContactActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alert.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(new Intent(DetailContactActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

Error:

```
01-02 02:05:41.493: D/AndroidRuntime(2927): Shutting down VM
01-02 02:05:41.493: D/AndroidRuntime(2927): --------- beginning of crash
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927): Process: com.example.phonedb, PID: 2927
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } from ProcessRecord{f5320c4 2927:com.example.phonedb/u0a69} (pid=2927, uid=10069) with revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2658)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:748)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at com.example.phonedb.DetailContactActivity.onClick(DetailContactActivity.java:127)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-02 02:05:41.616: E/AndroidRuntime(2927):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

here is the mainfest file,hope help::

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.phonedb"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.phonedb.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_contact" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.phonedb.DetailContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_contact" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 12):

Switch to **DIAL_PHONE**, as that does not need a permission.

**Just replace this line**

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

**to**

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

Answer (score 2):

Android 6 (SDK 23) allows users to revoke permissions from an app. I guess, thats what happened here. Your app must be able to cope with this situation.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html) for the details.

In particular:

> If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

Requsting permissions at runtime is [described in detail here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: me too i think so, but I couldn't know how to use it, how to get the permissions

Comment: I tried it's so hard, can't use it, is there any else solution, can I change the version to lower than 23 , plz help

Comment: where should I put the codes to request permission @Henry

Comment: Best is just before you need it. This makes it clear to the user why the permission is requested.

Answer (score 1):

Please change call_phone to dial phone. As you need to dial 
the number.

```
Intent callIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

or else try this too.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
```

> CALL_PRIVILEGED Allows an application to call any phone number,
>   including emergency numbers, without going through the Dialer user
>   interface for the user to confirm the call being placed.
>   **Not for use by third-party applications.**

Comment: where did you add the permission? can you post the android manifest file.

Comment: @Haneen edit your question and paste your Menifest.xml if u want to solve the issue.

Comment: I tried but it give me an error (Permission is only granted to system apps)

Answer (score 0):

i'm late. You must request permission dynamically.

```
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

more details at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html