# Permission Denial error onclick() function

Tags: java, android, permissions

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx
>   cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } from
>   ProcessRecord{9a25695 2469:in.preciseit.dialhingoli/u0a59} (pid=2469,
>   uid=10059) with revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE

here is what i want to ask in Logcat error 
I am using call function onClicklistener.
+

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please write the scenario too.

Comment: i am using call function in activity

Comment: @RavindraPawar Could you be more precise and please make some changes in your question because it is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: got it there is required permission in every activity in 6.0 or greater os..

Comment: @RavindraPawar edited it because it required a proper formatting. so that people can understand it. please be calm and mind your language. its not social networking site. everbody is here helping one or the other.

Comment: ok ..I am aware of it. see yours first.. not required this type of help.

Comment: Have you added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>` in to your manifest?

Comment: yes.. it is problem in marshmallow .. we have to give permission manually in activity

Answer (score 1):

please define following permission in menifest file and Try. And then after not work then Read [This url for marshmallow runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 6 (SDK 23) allows users to revoke permissions from an app.

[Click to read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562000/solve-the-error-revoked-permission-android-permission-call-phone)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11908952)

Comment: Thank u mohit Regarding my mistake next time i will give best answer with possible source code solution.